# Amazon MWS: Submit Prices and Quantity with ASIN

Tags: amazon-mws

I would like to update my products with the Amazon MWS API. The problem: I only have the products ASIN's to identify them. Not the SellerSKU.
As far as I have seen until now, the Feed to update the products Data does only accept the SKU  as an unique identifier for my product. Is there a way to get around this? Have I just missed the possibility to update with ASIN?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GetReport` operation with the `_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA` ReportType to retrieve a document that will associate the ASINs with SKUs.

Comment: Cool :) I guess this report can be useful for us in the future

Answer (score 0):

The SKU can be set by the Seller. In this case, the SKU was simply the Article No. Now I have the SKU and can simply use it.